# Browser is hanging up due to more and more Dom elements adding up

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 tree layout, which is expandable and collapsible from right click. For each collapse and expand more and more DOM elements are getting added up and after 10 odd operations browser is hanging up.
I tried removed the DOM elements by

```
mysvg = d3.select("#tree-container").select("svg");
d3.select(#mysvg).remove();
```

but still issue persists.

Can anyone has any idea on this?

Comment: Have you tried `mysvg.remove()`?

Comment: yes,I have tried it but of no use

Comment: And by "no use" you mean the the element wasn't removed, or that removing the element didn't help, or that you got some error message..?

Comment: Elements are not getting removed

Comment: In what context are you running this code? Is is possible that the browser is stuck using 100% CPU and therefore not executing the code?